# Plugin in cakePHP example

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I am learning cake PHP and can you please give a link of any plugin example . I need a simple tutorial of plugin or running example . Thanks in advance .

Comment: You've read [the docs in the CakePHP Cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/plugins.html#creating-your-own-plugins) already?

Comment: check the [cookbook](http://cook.cakephp.org/2.0/en/plugins.html).

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski yes I read out that but they not implement full plugin . I need full working plugin so I understand it clearly its flow . plz help ?

Comment: @didierc i read out that . but things not clear .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to create plugin the best solution is the [cakephp](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/plugins.html) book but if u are eager to write your own and find out the other tutorials 
like this [Plugin development tips and tricks](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/sky_l3ppard/2010/01/31/plugin-development-tips-and-tricks)  may help you but for the running example the best one is [debug kit](https://github.com/cakephp/debug_kit), it's recommended by cakephp.

Comment: I agree with this answer. Plugins take the same directory structure as your 'main' cakephp application. You can see them as 'mini' websites. However, keep in mind that a plugin does not *have* to be a full application, if you want to develop a plugin that only contains a *single* Helper, fine! Sometimes it's even better to do so, because you'll be able to add many 'simple' plugins to your projects/website if you need them. A nice example is the localised plugin, which contains only some validation rules and translation files; https://github.com/cakephp/localized